# Is it ethical to ask for a raise while looking for work

Tags: job-search, salary, ethics, negotiation

I haven't been offered a raise in my company for more than two years. In part this is because I had taken a job-protected leave, though I did some part time work for my current employer while I was out of the office. Now that I'm back to full time, it's time for me to get a raise.

In the meantime, a friend of mine is trying to get me into his organization. This is a big, public sector, unionized environment and have their payscale public, so I know for a fact my pay here would be higher than anything my current employer can offer. They have jobs available all the time, so my plan is to keep applying for positions I qualify for until someone from there offers me a position. Unfortunately this could be a month from now or a year from now or more, I can't tell.

My question is whether it's ethical for me to apply for positions and potentially GET a position elsewhere right after asking for and potentially receiving a raise at my current job. Would I be ethically obligated to stick around for awhile? In particular because I would need to ASK.

Comment: This post is somewhat related, but I'm not sure if a duplicate so not going to flag. Might be worth you reading. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64282/should-i-aggressively-negotiate-a-raise-when-im-planning-on-leaving-the-company/64296#64296

Comment: My reasons for leaving my current company for this new organization are basically purely money. I like working here, but the difference is tens of thousands of dollars, (if I include benefits) even if I DO get the raise I want to ask for. So the difference between that question and this I guess is that I'm respected here.

Comment: If the raise would actually keep you at the company, then I dont see why there is an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it would not. Hence the dilemma.

Comment: I guess the point is that I'm aiming at a specific organization and I don't know how long it will take to get there. What if it's not for a year?

Comment: Why not just wait and see if you get into the other organization? If you don't, ask for a raise. Not terribly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether it's ethical for me to apply for positions and potentially GET a position elsewhere right after asking for and potentially receiving a raise at my current job.

Maybe you are over-thinking this one. I don't see why you can't negotiate a raise while job-hunting, and I doubt that ethics is a thing that matters here, as seeking for a job is hardly unethical.

Although, to be honest, if you eventually get the raise and then you happen to quit shortly after that then I think that your current employer won't be much happy about that move.

> Would I be ethically obligated to stick around for awhile?

This would depend on the specifics of your contract, so not something we can answer completely.

What you surely have to do is to serve the notice period indicated in that contract, so expect to be required to serve it.

---

I see you commented that even though you got the raise you will most likely still not want to stay. If that is true then it is pointless to seek for a raise, and you could give your time better use by job-hunting instead.

Comment: I don't have a specific employment contract, so notice period would be as governed by employment standards. That includes nothing regarding sticking around post-raise, and definitely includes not quitting on the spot, which I wouldn't do anyways. I want a good reference! And aside from potentially quitting right after getting a raise, I have no reason to think I wouldn't get one.